# How to add right corner for progressbar in android

Tags: android

G'day there!

[image]

How to add corner like at left side for right side?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_tile">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change label `<clip>` to `<scale>` like this:

```
<scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
```

Comment: Github-flavored Markdown doesn't work here. Code formatting is done by indenting with 4 spaces or using the icon toolbar.